# How to fix TextView on Java, Android

Tags: java, android

I have the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="1">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
        <TextView 
            android:text="TextView" 
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
        <TextView 
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="123" 
            android:id="@+id/textView1" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

But I have a problem: If I put in TextView2 long text than TextView2 will be more longer default size and TextView1 will be more shortly default size. But I need than textview2 and textview1 have fixed size on width and will increase on height only. How can I do that? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
      <TextView 
        android:text="TextView" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
      <TextView 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="123" 
        android:id="@+id/textView1" 
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried it, but it is doesn't work for me... In my layout I use LinearLayout's, but you deleted it.. may be reason in that?

Comment: thank you, I add android:layout_width="0dp" to layouts and it is works!

Answer (score 1):

use these in both TextView..size depend on you what you want..i have give 50dp

```
android:maxWidth="50dp"
android:minWidth="50dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

You saying TextView width as fixed size: then you can use

`android:layout_width="150dp" or something`.., it makes your `TextView width fixed` and use 
`android:ellipsize="end"` to fix it.

and `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Hope it helps